# Hibernate Validator: Method constraints not evaluated

Tags: java, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

I have a simple class, which I'd like to validate:

```
public class Model {
    @NotNull
    private String someField;

    @AssertTrue
    public boolean methodConstraint() { ... }
}
```

This class is validated as part of the inputs of a spring controller method.

I managed to configure the validation of the fields (`someField` in this case), but for some reason the `methodConstraint()` isn't even invoked, let alone validated. I remember this being possible.

I use the default Spring boot 2.6.6 configuration for validation, which means I use the 6.2.3 version of hibernate validator, with the 2.0.2 API version.

I suspect it is the `ValidatorImpl:454` where thing go sideways, because this method only validates (direct) meta constraints, but method constraints don't seem to be considered as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have something like

```
@Controller
class ModelController {
    ...
    public Result mappedMethod(@Valid Model model) {
        ...
    }
}
```

then the model will be validated as a JavaBean. Meaning only fields and getters will be considered.

If a model class is modified to:

```
public class Model {
    @NotNull
    private String someField;

    @AssertTrue
    public boolean isMethodConstraint() { ... }
}
```

where the constrained method starts following the JavaBean requirements (method name begins with `is/get` and has 0 parameters) then that method will be executed during the validation.

Alternatively, if beans do not follow the JavaBean format then a custom strategy can be used. See the documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/6.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-getter-property-selection-strategy). But if possible - it'll be easier just to update the model classes and make constrained methods start with `is/get`.

Comment: I'd never have thought the solution would be something like this